# Function in my class is always getting called on page load, when I only want it called onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function that I want to call only onClick. However it's getting called right when the page loads, and then the onClick doesn't call it again afterwards.

handleIncrement() is what I'm trying to call, that's being called on load, and the button in render is where I'm trying to have it called onClick.

```
class Counter extends Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };

  handleIncrement() {
    console.log("Increment Clicked", this.state.count);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span style={{ fontSize: 20 }} className={this.getBadgeClasses()}>
          {this.formatCount()}
        </span>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleIncrement()}
          style={{ fontSize: 25 }}
          className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm 30"
        >
          Increment
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  getBadgeClasses() {
    let classes = "badge m-2 badge-";
    classes += this.state.count === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
    return classes;
  }

  formatCount() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return count === 0 ? "Zero" : count;
  }
}
```

Comment: As ford04 mentioned change the code to `onClick={() => this.handleIncrement()}` or `onClick={this.handleIncrement}` if you don't want to use an anonymous function which will help with stack tracing also. By adding the parentheses in your original code you are immediately executing handleIncrement on mount

Answer (score 2):

Change it to `onClick={() => this.handleIncrement()}`

Comment: Thank you! Watching a year old tutorial :/

Comment: haha, no problem. You could also use `onClick={this.handleIncrement}`, but then be aware that you have to bind the method in constructor (`this.handleIncrement = this.handleIncrement.bind(this)`). Or you can use private class properties

Answer (score 0):

`onClick={this.handleIncrememt}`